# Why nulls are appearing and proper reference of a combined variable

Tags: sql, sql-server

In the following code

```
SELECT x.[First Name] + ' ' + x.[Last Name] AS 'Combined Name'
FROM [Database1].[dbo].[InfoTable] x
WHERE 'Combined Name' IS NOT NULL
```

Combined table still pops up with Nulls.

Questions: Why? Is it because of the WHERE statement? Is it only acceptable to use fully qualified names such as

```
SELECT x.[First Name] + ' ' + x.[Last Name] AS 'Combined Name'
FROM [Database1].[dbo].[InfoTable] x
WHERE x.[First Name] + ' ' + x.[Last Name] IS NOT NULL
```

Things I've tried..different naming conventions and syntax, etc. The fully qualified names version works as expected, hence the question..just curious if I can use a shorter syntax that isn't completely spelled out. (In this example code was borrowed from a statement with multiple joins, so assume there are other tables in play)

Comment: No. The name does not exists yet at that point. (You also wouldn't use single quotes either.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This condition:

```
WHERE 'Combined Name' IS NOT NULL
```

Is comparing the constant string `'Combined Name'` to `NULL`.  It is evidently not `NULL` so this never returns false.

I would recommend that you *never* use single quotes to refer to column names -- too easily confused with strings as you do here.  The best bet is to choose names, such as `combined_name` that do not need to be escaped.

Oh, the answer to what you want to do is that you need a CTE, subquery, or lateral join, because you cannot refer to the column name in a `where`.  I might suggest:

```
SELECT v.combined_name
FROM [Database1].[dbo].[InfoTable] x CROSS APPLY
     (VALUES (x.[First Name] + ' ' + x.[Last Name])
     ) v(combined_name)
WHERE v.combined_name IS NOT NULL;
```